# CMake is having problems to compile a project which uses OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I'm on Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa.

I followed the instructions described [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html) to install OpenCV. Now I have it installed at the directory "/home/dell/opencv".

I tryed to run the example project located at "/home/dell/opencv/samples/cpp/example_cmake/" by running the command "cmake ." on terminal and I got the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any
  of the following names:

    OpenCVConfig.cmake
    opencv-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OpenCV"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/dell/opencv/samples/cpp/example_cmake/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

The "CMakeLists.txt" file contains the following:

```
# cmake needs this line
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

# Enable C++11
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED TRUE)

# Define project name
project(opencv_example_project)

# Find OpenCV, you may need to set OpenCV_DIR variable
# to the absolute path to the directory containing OpenCVConfig.cmake file
# via the command line or GUI
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

# If the package has been found, several variables will
# be set, you can find the full list with descriptions
# in the OpenCVConfig.cmake file.
# Print some message showing some of them
message(STATUS "OpenCV library status:")
message(STATUS "    config: ${OpenCV_DIR}")
message(STATUS "    version: ${OpenCV_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "    libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
message(STATUS "    include path: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

# Declare the executable target built from your sources
add_executable(opencv_example example.cpp)

# Link your application with OpenCV libraries
target_link_libraries(opencv_example LINK_PRIVATE ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

I've searched a lot through the internet and it seems to be a common problem. However, I still didn't manage to solve it by following the intructions that I've found.

One thing that I notice when going through the OpenCV folder is that the version that I have (which I think it's the most recent one) indeed doesn't contain any "OpenCVConfig.cmake" file, as you can see [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/cmake). However, an oldest version of OpenCV that I found on github have this file, as you can see [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/2f4e38c8313ff313de7c41141d56d945d91f47cf/cmake/OpenCVConfig.cmake).

So, maybe some configuration is set to this oldest version and it's causing conflict? How to change that and get it working for the newest version? I think it must be something simple to solve but I'm quite newbie.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMake writes you what to do:

> Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
>    "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.

Another option - please, read comments in the file `CMakeLists.txt` that you've pasted, once more.

They say:

> you may need to set OpenCV_DIR variable
>   to the absolute path to the directory containing OpenCVConfig.cmake

Another issue - in-source build, performed with passing dot to cmake. It is better to create separate directory for build files.

Building this way allows you easily adding your build directory to `.gitignore` and not polluting your source code repository with compiled binaries. Also, if something goes wrong, you can just remove that build directory and start again from scratch. That is much easier than messing with files one by one.

So, you need to call CMake like following

```
mkdir build
cd build 
OpenCV_DIR=/home/dell/opencv cmake ..
```

or

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/dell/opencv
```

or the following also should do the trick

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DOpenCV_DIR=/home/dell/opencv
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But my problem is that there is no "OpenCVConfig.cmake" file in the OpenCV version that I've installed (the one indicated in my post). I think that last versions of OpenCV doesn't contain it. But for some reason it's being demanded when compiling with CMake.

Comment: Did you do `make install`? `OpenCVConfig.cmake` is generated on installation

Comment: I just cloned the OpenCV [repository](https://github.com/opencv/opencv) by writing:

```git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git

git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git
``` 
as indicated by the official [guide](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html).
Isn't the correct way to install it? How I should do that exactly? Thanks for answer

Comment: It appears, you've done only the first point out of 10 (including optional), listed in the instruction. Please, do the rest (configure, `make`, `make install`). Only then will you be able to compile samples.

Comment: Aah I'm a dumb... I think you're right. I'll try to run the rest of the procedure and after I say if it's ok. I thought it was different ways of doing the same thing.

Comment: After cloning the repository using:


```
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git
```

I ran:

```
cd ~/opencv
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```
And got an error:

```
_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/dell/opencv ..
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (message):
  

  FATAL: In-source builds are not allowed.

         You should create a separate directory for build files.



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: Looks like `cd build` failed

Comment: I created a "build" folder inside the "opencv" folder and ran the indicated commands from it. What could be wrong?

Comment: Try removing spaces between `-D` and `CMA...`: `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .....`

Comment: Ok, I tryed run
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/dell/opencv ..
 from the build folder (which is inside the opencv folder) and still got the same error

Comment: Get it now. I had to run rm ../CMakeCache.txt before running the cmake command. I will try to finish the procedure now. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Update your OpenCV search directory path as below,

```
find_package(OpenCV 3.4 REQUIRED PATHS "/usr/local/opencv/" NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
```